# addOBV throwing error

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to plot a graph with price and a few technical indicators such as ADX, RSI, and OBV. I cannot figure out why `addOBV` is giving an error and why `addADX` not showing at all in the graph lines in the chart?

Here my code:

```
tmp <- read.csv(paste("ProcessedQuotes/",Nifty[x,],".csv", sep=""),
  as.is=TRUE, header=TRUE, row.names=NULL)
tmp$Date<-as.Date(tmp$Date)
ydat = xts(tmp[,-1],tmp$Date) 
lineChart(ydat, TA=NULL, name=paste(Nifty[x,]," Technical Graph"))
plot(addSMA(10))
plot(addEMA(10))
plot(addRSI())
plot(addADX())
plot(addOBV())
```

Error for `addOBV` is:

```
Error in try.xts(c(2038282, 1181844, -1114409, 1387404, 3522045, 4951254,  : 
  Error in as.xts.double(x, ..., .RECLASS = TRUE) :   
        order.by must be either 'names()' or otherwise specified
```

Below you can see DIn is not shown fully in the graphs.

[image]

```
> class(ydat)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> head(ydat)
  Open  High    Low  Close  Volume Trades Sma20 Sma50 DIp DIn DX ADX aroonUp aroonDn oscillator  macd signal RSI14
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible...

Comment: I agree with @PaulHiemstra. The problem could be with your data. Use `getSymbols` to pull data from Yahoo Finance, and please add the output from `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: addOBV uses close and volume, which is existing in the ydat as shown in the head(ydat)..  All other tech indicators are working..  I shown one link on internet saying there is a patch for quantmod, to solve this error, but when tried to apply the patch, said cannot be applied to my version of R

Comment: Session info> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.3-17 TTR_0.21-1      xts_0.8-8       zoo_1.7-9       Defaults_1.1-1

Comment: Here the linkhttp://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=546&aid=2391&group_id=125

Comment: For future reference, we prefer _minimal_ reproducible examples.  I don't see why it's necessary to include all the other add* calls.  `addOBV` was the one that gave you a problem, and it gives you the problem whether you call, e.g. `addSMA` first or not, so you don't need to include it in your question.  Also, see from my answer how you can use yahoo data so that your code is reproducible (we don't have your csv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why that patch doesn't work for you, but you can just create a new function (or you could mask the one from quantmod).  Let's just make a new, patched version called `addOBV2` which is the code for `addOBV` except for the one patched line.  (`x <- as.matrix(lchob@xdata)` is replaced with `x <- try.xts(lchob@xdata, error=FALSE)`).

```
addOBV2 <- function (..., on = NA, legend = "auto") 
{
  stopifnot("package:TTR" %in% search() || require("TTR", quietly = TRUE))
  lchob <- quantmod:::get.current.chob()
  x <- try.xts(lchob@xdata, error=FALSE)
  #x <- as.matrix(lchob@xdata)
  x <- OBV(price = Cl(x), volume = Vo(x))
  yrange <- NULL
  chobTA <- new("chobTA")
  if (NCOL(x) == 1) {
    chobTA@TA.values <- x[lchob@xsubset]
  }
  else chobTA@TA.values <- x[lchob@xsubset, ]
  chobTA@name <- "chartTA"
  if (any(is.na(on))) {
    chobTA@new <- TRUE
  }
  else {
    chobTA@new <- FALSE
    chobTA@on <- on
  }
  chobTA@call <- match.call()
  legend.name <- gsub("^.*[(]", " On Balance Volume (", deparse(match.call()))#, 
  #extended = TRUE)
  gpars <- c(list(...), list(col=4))[unique(names(c(list(col=4), list(...))))]
  chobTA@params <- list(xrange = lchob@xrange, yrange = yrange, 
                        colors = lchob@colors, color.vol = lchob@color.vol, multi.col = lchob@multi.col, 
                        spacing = lchob@spacing, width = lchob@width, bp = lchob@bp, 
                        x.labels = lchob@x.labels, time.scale = lchob@time.scale, 
                        isLogical = is.logical(x), legend = legend, legend.name = legend.name, 
                        pars = list(gpars))
  if (is.null(sys.call(-1))) {
    TA <- lchob@passed.args$TA
    lchob@passed.args$TA <- c(TA, chobTA)
    lchob@windows <- lchob@windows + ifelse(chobTA@new, 1, 
                                            0)
    chartSeries.chob <- quantmod:::chartSeries.chob
    do.call("chartSeries.chob", list(lchob))
    invisible(chobTA)
  }
  else {
    return(chobTA)
  }
}
```

Now it works.

```
# reproduce your data
ydat <- getSymbols("ZEEL.NS", src="yahoo", from="2012-09-11", 
                   to="2013-01-18", auto.assign=FALSE)

lineChart(ydat, TA=NULL, name=paste("ZEEL Technical Graph"))
plot(addSMA(10))
plot(addEMA(10))
plot(addRSI())
plot(addADX())
plot(addOBV2())
```

[image]

Comment: I just committed this patch to quantmod on R-Forge, r603.

Answer (score 3):

This code reproduces the error:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
lineChart(AAPL, 'last 6 months')
addOBV()
```

Session Info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.3-17 TTR_0.21-1      xts_0.9-1       zoo_1.7-9       Defaults_1.1-1  rgeos_0.2-11   
[7] sp_1.0-5        sos_1.3-5       brew_1.0-6     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.0    lattice_0.20-6 tools_2.15.0
```

Googling around, the error seems to be related to the fact that `addOBV` converts the data into a matrix, which causes problems with `TTR::OBV`. A patch has been [posted on RForge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2391&group_id=125&atid=546).

Comment: @user1848880, to apply the patch, you'd have to checkout or download the source code, then download the patch separately, and patch the code (e.g. on linux follow [these instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appy-patch-file-using-patch-command/)).  Then, once you've patched the source code locally, you have to build and install the patched version of the package.

Comment: install.packages("quantmod.patch")
Warning message:
package ‘quantmod.patch’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)